# Magento get configurable product from simple product even if config product is disabled

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I need to get the parent configurable product from a simple product, even if the parent product is marked as disabled. I also need to get the status of the configurable product (enabled or disabled).

Right now I'm getting the parent product like this:

```
$parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());
if (isset($parentIds[0])) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentIds[0]);
}
```

This works perfectly unless the configurable product has been disabled, where the $parentIds array is empty. I need to get the configurable product even if it's disabled, and also determine if the configurable product is enabled/disabled.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've done a little digging around, and I can't seem to reproduce your issue.

When I call getParentIdsByChild() on a simple with a disabled configurable, I still get the parent product ID.

```
$parentIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')
      ->getParentIdsByChild(14412);
var_dump($parentIds);
```

Gives me:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "14446"
}
```

14446 has a status of disabled. I've also tried it as in stock and out of stock.

Looking at the actual function on the resource file

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Type_Configurable::getParentIdsByChild()
```

I can see that it looks in the table `catalog_product_super_link` which doesn't have any fields for status, and therefore should always return the parent ID, if the product link exists.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your effort! I'll do a little bit of research on my end to see what else could be causing this - I assumed that the problem was caused by the product being disabled as this seemed to be a common element, but perhaps I've missed something.

Comment: +1 I was able to get both disabled and enabled product Ids from this.